# GraphQL response in XML

Tags: json, xml, graphql

I'm working in a GraphQL API, and recently I was reading the documentation and it says that GQL doesn't require a specific serialization format, but JSON is the most common response of the GQL Queries.

Here's the document that I read:
https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Execution

So I was looking for some projects that uses other response type, XML specifically, and I don't have lucky. My doubt is, can I use XML as serialization format for the Query response? or how can I parse the JSON response to XML?

Comment: Underscore-java library has static methods U.jsonToXml(json) and U.xmlToJson(xml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting JSON to XML is trivial.  You can use [this](https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/21.1/ug-editor/topics/convert-JSON-to-XML-x-tools.html) web-based tool, for example.  Of course, this can also be done programmatically by virtually every language.

As for examples of graphQL projects that return XML, I don't know of any.  Hope this helps!